# Bash 'unbound variable' error when variables are referenced in multiline comment (set -u)

Tags: linux, bash, variable, error-handling, here-document

I have an unexpected behaviour- following snippet fail with 'unbound variable' error:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u
<<EOF
a=a
b=$a
EOF
```

Tested on:

GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release

GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you have defined with `set -u` is force an exit with an error message, if attempted to use undefined variable ([The `set` builtin command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/set)).

The form of here-documents `<<` with `EOF` is equivalent to as if double-quoting the words inside to allow the variables to be expanded (parameter expansion) by the shell (`bash` in this case; also subject to  command substitution and arithmetic expansion). To avoid the expansion from happening quote the here-string with a single quote

```
set -u
<<'EOF'
a=a
b=$a
EOF
```